# URL gets added twice in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, routes, nested-routes, laravel-8

When I press a navigation button for the second time, for some reason
the URL in the browser is being repetitive twice. To clarify, the first button click sends the user to the correct URL, the second click fails due to the duplication of the URL.

Observations:

1. I suspect that it might be due to the relative path, thus when pressing the button twice the system thing it should add the relative path again.
2. I am using @extends and suspect that the system tries to load @extends twice.

---

Pressing button first time (visible URL):

`http://localhost:8000/sites/tax-declarations/add-data`

Pressing the same button a second time (visible URL):

`http://localhost:8000/sites/tax-declarations/sites/tax-declarations/add-data`

**Routes**

Route::view('/sites/tax-declarations/add-data',
'pages/sites/tax_declarations/add_data');

**Navigation Blade**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="sites/tax-declarations/add-data">Add data</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with Laravel 7?

Comment: Because Laravel 8 came out 2 days ago and even though I see the problem in my current environment (Laravel 8) I recall having seen the same problem in Laravel 7. I removed the Laravel 7 tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: you are using a relative URL, this is how they work (it is adding what you have there to the current directory/segment) ... either add a `/` to the beginning to make it relative to the root of the site or use a URL helper to generate an absolute URL  ... this has nothing to do with Laravel

Comment: @lagbox I kept the routes file intact ,but added the initial `/` in the navigation files href path. Please move your explanation into an answer and I will go ahead and approve it.

Comment: as you wish :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using relative URLs the path in that 'href' will be appended to the current directory/segment you are at. You can add a `/` to the beginning of your relative path to make this path now relative to the root of the site.

A better option is probably to use one of the URL helpers to generate an absolute URL for you:

```
<a href="{{ url('sites/tax-declarations/add-data') }}">...</a>
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - URL Generation - Generating Basic URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#generating-basic-urls) `url`